# REST API and JWT authentication : send data along token?

Tags: javascript, rest, authentication, jwt, restful-authentication

I'm working on a javascript application using a REST API.
Authentication is made with **JWT tokens** stored in **cookies**

Right now, this scenario is implemented:

- user sign in with credentials. Client calls `POST /token` to authenticate
- server responds with a HTTP-only cookie containing the token.
- once authenticated, client makes another request to get all user data (`GET /me`)

I would like to make this process as fast as possible and reduce the number of server requests as much as possible. I thought about combining `/token` and `/me` calls and get token and user data in the same request.

That could be done in different ways :

- in the claims of the token, but client won't be able to use it as it's in a HTTP-only cookie.
- in another, non HTTP-only, cookie but that will be sent uselessly with every future request, so I don't like this solution
- in the response body when server sends the cookie after authentication but I have the feeling that it goes against the REST principles as we send user data from an authentication endpoint.

Is there a way to make this process more simple while respecting standard processes and REST principles?

Answer (score 0):

I personnally use Cookies as a storage, but not in HTTPonly mode. In this case, the simplest is to encode the information you need inside the token.

Are you forced to use HTTP-only cookies? Is it an option for you to change it (in fact, for that you must master the authorization server)?

Another thing : using GET to pass credentials isn't safe as you probably pass your credentials in the URL, which can be fetched from server logs. Prefer POST (and HTTPS of course).

Few pointers about JWT and their storage stategies:

- [Tokens vs Cookies](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/27/ten-things-you-should-know-about-tokens-and-cookies/)
- [Where to store the tokens?](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage)
- [Threats of token theft](https://auth0.com/forum/t/stealing-jwt-from-authenticated-user/352)

Comment: I use HTTP-only cookies for security reasons, to avoid vulnerability on XSS attacks for instance. With a protection against CSRF, I'm all good. 
And I don't want to carry too much informations in my cookies either. They will be sent on every request, so the lighter the better.

Actually, I'm already using POST to pass credentials, just a mistake in writing this question ;)